# .net CheckBoxList losing selected property after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList nested in a Repeater that is dynamically populated in the Repeater's OnItemDataBound.  On a button click I would like to save the changes to each check box list, but the selected property is always TRUE after postback.

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptFields" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptField_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField id="hFieldID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' />
    <asp:Label id="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description")%>' />
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="chkOptions" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBoxList>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    rptFields.DataSource = Fields;
    rptFields.DataBind();
  }
}

protected void rptField_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    CheckBoxList chkOptions = (CheckBoxList)e.Items.FindControl("chkOptions");
    Field ThisField = (Field)e.Item.DataItem;

    for (int i = 0; i < ThisField.Options.Length; i++)
    {                   
        ListItem liOption = new ListItem (ThisField.Options [i].Description, ThisField.Options [i].ID.ToString ());

        liOption.Selected = ThisField.Options [i].Selected;

        chkOptions.Items.Add (liOption);
    }
  }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in rptFields)
  {
    int iFieldID = int.parse(rptItem.FindControl("hFieldID"));
    Field ThisField = GetFieldByID(iFieldID);
    CheckBoxList chkOptions = (CheckBoxList)rptItem.FindControl("chkOptions");

    foreach(Option ThisOption in ThisField.Options)
    {
      for(int i = 0;i < chkOptions.Items.Count; i++)
      {
        int OptionID = int.parse(chkOptions.Items[i].Value);
        if(ThisOption.ID == OptionID)
        {
          //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
          //SELECTED IS ALWAYS TRUE
          ThisOption.Selected = chkOptions.Items[i].Selected;
          ThisOption.Save();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All the data from the repeater persists, including the text and value fields of the check box list items.  All except the selected property.

I have searched and searched for an answer and none exist.  Every similar issue was people re-binding the list in each postback. As you can see that is not the case here.  And for what it's worth, the exact same solution works for radio button lists no problem.

EDIT: For the record this project is running Mono.net 4.5

UPDATE: The same solution works in another project we have built using .Net 2.0.  I'm not sure if it's a Mono issue or there is a configuration setting that changes the behaviour of the post back.

Comment: I would think that you would have `If(IsPostBack){ } else{ }`  you can actually check the behavior of what you have currently if you setup break points in the Page_Load event as well as your btnSave_Click Event. also `ListItem liOption` create that as a static or protected at the class level. or learn to use Session variables. and case the values back as ListItem

Comment: An else{ } on the If(IsPostBack) doesn't de me any good because I have nothing else that needs to be done in the Page_Load.  As for the btnSave_Click I am using breakpoints to confirm the state of the Selected property.  I know how to use session variables, but I'm not sure how I would store the state to each check box in each list in session without performing a postback.  All the other values are carried forward in the ViewState, why not the selected property?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar  problem recently, to solve it you can store it in querystring.

Comment: this is not really a good answer.. it would be better in that case to store it in a Session Variable..

Comment: What good would storing it in session (or QueryString) do me?  I lose the property at postback and don't know which check boxes are selected until the user clicks save....

Comment: because you need to understand Page Life Cycle as well as what postbacks are and what triggers postbacks.. you can also accomplish this via javascript also look up how to use the `__DoPostBack` function what you are trying to do is not difficult @BrycePat

Comment: Well @MethodMan I do understand what postabacks are and what triggers them.  I don't see how using __DoPostBack to trigger one using javascript would fix the problem.  The problem is that the selected property is not being persisted.  You haven't actually provided a solution.  Could you please?

Comment: Methodman is corect,my solution was posting to a web service and i could not use a session variable but in this case you can and should.

Comment: @Dwight, what am I missing?  I'm unclear on why I NEED to use a web service or session variable.  Why would the property be lost on the button click?  And why would the exact same solution work with a RadioButtonList but not the CheckBoxList?  Besides how would I even store it in session, if the property has changed as soon as it is posted to the server?

Comment: you do not.need a web service but you need a web service , I was printing out that in my situation posting to a web service, I had to pass some information using a query string.

Comment: you do not.need a web service but you need a web service , I was printing out that in my situation posting to a web service, I had to pass some information using a query string. A session variable is needed in your case it's not going to change on post it's scope is application wide as opposed to you controls which only exists while you form is loaded. I have notices that radii button sometimes get check on post back and load events. look here for more info on session variables http://w3school.com/asp_ssessions.asp